# PHP MySQL Insert survey answers into table

Tags: php, mysql

If i have this HTML and PHP Code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $num = $_POST['number'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)
    {
        if($i==0)
        {
            echo '0';
            $answer1 = $_POST["answer1"];
            $answer2 = $_POST["answer2"];
            $answer3 = $_POST["answer3"];
            $answer4 = $_POST["answer4"];
            $answer5 = $_POST["answer5"];
            $answer6 = $_POST["answer6"];
            $answer7 = $_POST["answer7"];
            $answer8 = $_POST["answer8"];
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'no 0';
            $answer1 = $_POST["answer1$i"];
            $answer2 = $_POST["answer2$i"];
            $answer3 = $_POST["answer3$i"];
            $answer4 = $_POST["answer4$i"];
            $answer5 = $_POST["answer5$i"];
            $answer6 = $_POST["answer6$i"];
            $answer7 = $_POST["answer7$i"];
            $answer8 = $_POST["answer8$i"];
        }
        //then insert the line items into the lineitems table with the bill sequence from the adhocbills table
        $sql="INSERT into surveys_completed (survey_sequence, question_seq, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer5, answer6, answer7, answer8) values ('".$_POST["survey_sequence"]."', '".$_POST["question_seq"]."', '".$answer1."', '".$answer2."', '".$answer3."', '".$answer4."', '".$answer5."', '".$answer6."', '".$answer7."', '".$answer8."')";
        $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
        echo $sql.'<br><br>';
    }
}
?>

<?php
/*
if(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["string"]) == '')
{
    echo 'No Survey was selected';
    exit();
} */
if(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["company"]) != '')
{
    //sql for company
    $sql="SELECT * from surveys where company = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["company"])."' and string = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["string"])."' ";
}
elseif(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["string"]) != '')
{
    //sql for string
    $sql="SELECT * from surveys where string = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["string"])."' ";
}
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
$survey=mysql_fetch_array($rs);

echo '<h3>'.$survey["title"].'</h3>';
?>
<form method="post" action="/home.php?id=surveys/complete_survey">
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<?php
$sql2="SELECT * from surveys_questions where survey_seq = '".$survey["sequence"]."' ";
$rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
$counter=0;
while($survey_questions=mysql_fetch_array($rs2))
{
    $counter++;
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><strong><?php echo $counter; ?>. <?php echo $survey_questions["question"]; ?></strong>
        COUNTER<input type="text" name="number" id="number" value="<?php echo $counter; ?>" />
        SURVEY<input type="text" name="survey_sequence" id="survey_sequence" value="<?php echo $survey["sequence"]; ?>" />
        QUESTION<input type="text" name="question_seq" id="question_seq" value="<?php echo $survey_questions["sequence"]; ?>" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php if($survey_questions["answer1"] != '') { echo '<input type="checkbox" name="answer1'.$counter.'" value="Y" /> '.$survey_questions["answer1"]; } ?></td>
        <td><?php if($survey_questions["answer2"] != '') { echo '<input type="checkbox" name="answer2'.$counter.'" value="Y" /> '.$survey_questions["answer2"]; } ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php if($survey_questions["answer3"] != '') { echo '<input type="checkbox" name="answer3'.$counter.'" value="Y" /> '.$survey_questions["answer3"]; } ?></td>
        <td><?php if($survey_questions["answer4"] != '') { echo '<input type="checkbox" name="answer4'.$counter.'" value="Y" /> '.$survey_questions["answer4"]; } ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php if($survey_questions["answer5"] != '') { echo '<input type="checkbox" name="answer5'.$counter.'" value="Y" /> '.$survey_questions["answer5"]; } ?></td>
        <td><?php if($survey_questions["answer6"] != '') { echo '<input type="checkbox" name="answer6'.$counter.'" value="Y" /> '.$survey_questions["answer6"]; } ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php if($survey_questions["answer7"] != '') { echo '<input type="checkbox" name="answer7'.$counter.'" value="Y" /> '.$survey_questions["answer7"]; } ?></td>
        <td><?php if($survey_questions["answer8"] != '') { echo '<input type="checkbox" name="answer8'.$counter.'" value="Y" /> '.$survey_questions["answer8"]; } ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Complete Survey" />
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

So the code selects the survey from the survey table and then gets all the questions from survey_questions for the selected survey.

Each question has up to 8 answers (all checkboxes with value of Y)

The user goes though and checks the box for the answer(s) they choose so when the form is submitted, how can i make it insert into surveys_completed table each answer.

So for each question, it adds a row in the surveys_completed table.

The structure of the surveys_completed table is:

sequence
survey_sequence
question_seq
answer1
answer2
answer3
answer4
answer5
answer6
answer7
answer8

Comment: You need to submit the form to another PHP page (`<input type="submit">`) which would then read the values from the $_POST variable and populate the database

Comment: there is a while loop in my code so basically it shows multiple questions (a question per row in table surveys_questions) so i want to be able to answer each question and put a Y in the columns in the table surveys_completed (answer1, answer2, answer3 etc...)

Comment: so if there are 2 rows(questions) in table surveys_questions they will display and the user needs to answer the questions using the checkboxes. if answer 1 is checked on the first question it will add a row in surveys_completed with survey_sequence and question_seq = $survey_questions["sequence"]
hopefully im making sense

Comment: any ideas - best way round this?

Comment: so you want to update the table as soon as the checkbox is checked?

Answer (score 0):

create a page called getval.php then put the below code and you have to make sure you
connect to the database using pdo thats when this code is gonna work for you .
H i hope it will help you good luck

```
<?php 
$answer1=(isset($_POST['answer1']))? trim($_POST['answer1']): '';
$answer2=(isset($_POST['answer2']))? trim($_POST['answer2']): '';
$answer3=(isset($_POST['answer3']))? trim($_POST['answer3']): '';
$answer4=(isset($_POST['answer4']))? trim($_POST['answer4']): '';
$answer5=(isset($_POST['answer5']))? trim($_POST['answer5']): '';
$answer6=(isset($_POST['answer6']))? trim($_POST['answer6']): '';
$answer7=(isset($_POST['answer7']))? trim($_POST['answer7']): '';
$answer8=(isset($_POST['answer8']))? trim($_POST['answer8']): '';
$query="INSERT INTO surveys_completed(
answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4,answer5,answer5,answer6,answer7,answer8 )
VALUES(:answer1,:answer2,:answer3,:answer4,:answer5,:answer5,
:answer6,:answer7,:answer8)";
$insert = $con->prepare($query);
$insert->execute(array(
':answer1'=>$answer1,
':answer2'=>$answer2,
':answer3'=>$answer3,
':answer4'=>$answer4,
':answer5'=>$answer5,
':answer6'=>$answer6,
':answer7'=>$answer7,
':answer8'=>$answer8
));
?>
```